# Recursive function return appears different in calling script.

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am testing the contents of the array, `$list`, I will return as I cycle through these recursive function calls.

There is a hard limit of 25 records to be fetched at a time.

On calls where the result set is equal to the limit I increment an offset and recurse sending the current array of results as an argument.

From inside these loops I dump the $list var and other details into an email indicating whether recursing or returning and the current counts and a dump of the $list array.

These emails contain exactly what I expect numbers-wise and in `$list`.

The calling script however seems to get a different `$list` containing only the last loop.  In cases where the result set is over 25 `$list` is empty.  If the whole set is under 25 it is correct in the calling script output.

Can someone please straighten me out on why `$list` seems different inside the function than it is after it returns?

Calling script:

```
$levels = get_membership_levels();
        if ($levels) {
            foreach ($levels as $l) {
                echo "<h2>$l</h2>\n";
                $members = get_current_members_by_level($l);
                echo '<h2>' . count($members) . '</h2>';
```

Function:

```
function get_current_members_by_level($level, $offset = 0, $list = array()) {
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php';
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php';
 $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton( );
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php';
 $result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', array(
    'membership_type_id' => "$level",
    'limit' => 1000,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'api.Contact.get' => array(array('limit' => 1000, 'sort' => 'last_name')),
 ));

 if ($result['values']) {
    foreach ($result['values'] as $k => $v) {
        $member = get_member($v['contact_id']);
        if ($member) {
            $list[]= $member;
        } 
    }
    if (count($result['values']) >= 25) { 
        $offset+= 25;
        mail('email@example.com', "Recursing for $level - current set= " . count($result['values']) . ' Total: ' . count($list) . ' Offset= ' . $offset,print_r($list,1));
        get_current_members_by_level($level, $offset, $list);
    } else {
        mail('email@example.com', "Returning result for $level - current set= " . count($result['values']) . ' Total: ' . count($list) . ' Offset= ' . $offset,print_r($list,1));
        return $list;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code is that you dont use the return or your function get_current_members_by_level();

```
if (count($result['values']) >= 25) { 
        $offset+= 25;
        mail('email@example.com', "Recursing for $level - current set= " . count($result['values']) . ' Total: ' . count($list) . ' Offset= ' . $offset,print_r($list,1));
        get_current_members_by_level($level, $offset, $list); // this function return the list but you dont use it.
    } else {
        mail('email@example.com', "Returning result for $level - current set= " . count($result['values']) . ' Total: ' . count($list) . ' Offset= ' . $offset,print_r($list,1));
        return $list;
    }
```

this should be instead

```
if (count($result['values']) >= 25) { 
        $offset+= 25;
        mail('email@example.com', "Recursing for $level - current set= " . count($result['values']) . ' Total: ' . count($list) . ' Offset= ' . $offset,print_r($list,1));
        $list = get_current_members_by_level($level, $offset, $list); // now the new list will be in the var $list
    } else {
        mail('email@example.com', "Returning result for $level - current set= " . count($result['values']) . ' Total: ' . count($list) . ' Offset= ' . $offset,print_r($list,1));
        return $list;
    }
```